# Not able to see Shiny app on docker at given port?

Tags: docker, shiny, dockerfile

I am new for docker, I am trying to run a shiny application on docker at giver port 3838. below is the docker file:

```
# get shiny serves plus tidyverse packages image
FROM rocker/shiny-verse:latest

# system libraries of general use
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev 
  

# install R packages required 
# (change it dependeing on the packages you need)
RUN R -e "install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('shinydashboard', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "devtools::install_github('andrewsali/shinycssloaders')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('lubridate', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('magrittr', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('glue', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('DT', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('plotly', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('shinybusy', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"


# copy the app to the image

COPY testapp.R /srv/shiny-server/

# Copy further configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.sh /usr/bin/shiny-server.sh

# Copy configuration files into the Docker image
COPY shiny-server.conf  /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf


# select port
EXPOSE 3838

# allow permission
RUN sudo chown -R shiny:shiny /srv/shiny-server

# run app
CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh",  "-e", "production"]
```

directory:
[image]

cmd screen:

[image]

after this I am not able to see my applcation on localhost:3838

[image]

Comment: If you run the server without docker (like a regular process) does it work on `localhost:3838` ? try to look at the container's logs and check for errors (`docker logs container_name`)

Comment: You can try changing the shiny server host to `0.0.0.0`.

Comment: should probably do a `docker ps` to ensure your server is actually running and not breaking due to a runtime error.
Maybe even do `docker run -it ...` so you can bind the tty and check the logs

Comment: I am getting below response:
C:\Arinjay_Intern\Work\Docker\firstdockerapp>docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
8a3a2850ea56        my-shinyapp-image   "/usr/bin/shiny-se..."   43 minutes ago      Up 43 minutes       0.0.0.0:3838->3838/tcp   objective_noyce

C:\Arinjay_Intern\Work\Docker\firstdockerapp>docker logs ojective_noyce
Error response from daemon: No such container: ojective_noyce

Comment: Not able to see logs:

C:\Arinjay_Intern\Work\Docker\firstdockerapp>docker logs wonderful_lamport

C:\Arinjay_Intern\Work\Docker\firstdockerapp>docker logs wonderful_lamport

C:\Arinjay_Intern\Work\Docker\firstdockerapp>docker container logs wonderful_lamport

Comment: @jakub how I can change shiny-server host to 0.0.0.0

Comment: It should be running on 127.0.0.1/localhost, when you use -p flag, you add port forwarding rule on host to go from localhost:3838.
do `docker run -it -p 3838:3838 --entrypoint bash my-shinyapp-image` to exec into the container on start up and run your server from inside

Comment: anyone can demonstrate a simple shiny application on docker. I want a very simple application just dockerfile and app.R on localhost:4040

Comment: Found this example from a google search: https://www.r-bloggers.com/deploying-an-r-shiny-app-with-docker/